# Can hashmap can be of return type of function as well?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I was going through this sample code and am not able to follow and understand the code.

- which part is return type in main function and which are attribute and function name .
- And then can we add arraylist as a value for a key in map ?
- How does it iterate using for loop using entryset () and puts Arraylist of those tree type into map --

```
public HashMap<String,ArrayList> splitToKategorieArrays(HashMap<Integer, Teilnehmer> teilnehmerListe )
```

Can you please explain that function type? Is it a function with hashmap as the return type?

```
public HashMap<String,ArrayList<Teilnehmer>> splitToKategorieArrays(HashMap<Integer, Teilnehmer> teilnehmerListe ){

    ArrayList<Teilnehmer> junioren = new ArrayList<Teilnehmer>();
    ArrayList<Teilnehmer> senioren = new ArrayList<Teilnehmer>();
    ArrayList<Teilnehmer> elite = new ArrayList<Teilnehmer>();
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Teilnehmer>> teilnehmerSplit = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Teilnehmer>>();

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Teilnehmer> entry : teilnehmerListe.entrySet()) {
        Teilnehmer teilnehmer = entry.getValue();
        if (teilnehmer.getKategorie() == 1){
            junioren.add(teilnehmer);
        } else if (teilnehmer.getKategorie() == 2){
            senioren.add(teilnehmer);
        } else if (teilnehmer.getKategorie() == 3){
            elite.add(teilnehmer);
        }
    }
    teilnehmerSplit.put("junioren",junioren);
    teilnehmerSplit.put("senioren",senioren);
    teilnehmerSplit.put("elite",elite);

    return teilnehmerSplit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is the return type of the method. Where is your confusion? What else do you think that could it be?

Comment: Yes. A function can return a `HashMap`. Just like it can return any other type of object.

Comment: Yes.  That method creates a new `HashMap`, puts three entries into that `HashMap`, then returns it.  So the return type is `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Teilnehmer>>`.  When you call this method, you'll probably want to assign its return value to a variable of that type.  Or possibly just `Map<String,ArrayList<Teilnehmer>>`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Can you please explain me how that for loop works ..

Comment: Sure.  That loop just iterates through the entries in `teilnehmerListe`, copying each one to one of three new lists, depending on its `Kategorie`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it is quite fine for a function to return a hashmap.

The given code snippet just groups the `Teilnehmer` values in the input hashmap by the categories (1, 2, or 3), adds these values into separate lists, and puts the lists into a new map with the string keys.

It is possible to rewrite this method in more concise form using Java Stream API, particularly `filter` for the categories, and `groupingBy` collector to create a map of `<String, List<Teilnehmer>>`:

```java
public HashMap<String, List<Teilnehmer>> splitToKategorieArrays(HashMap<Integer, Teilnehmer> teilnehmerListe ) {
    // prepare string names of the categories
    String[] categories = {
        "junioren",
        "senioren",
        "elite"
    };
    return teilnehmerListe
        .values()
        .stream() // stream of Teilnehmer objects
        // categories should be in range [1..3]
        .filter(tn -> 0 < tn.getKategorie() && tn.getKategorie() <= 3)
        // -1 to match index in `categories` array
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tn -> categories[tn.getKategorie() - 1]));
}
```

Comment: hi Alex can you please explain me how that for loop works .. i couldnt follow that well

Comment: hi, which `for` loop do you refer to?  In your post?